# Playing Mpeg-Dash streams in Apple Tv when casting from iOS using Airplay

Tags: ios, apple-tv, drm, airplay, mpeg-dash

I have a applications which uses the DRM services like I play MS3 Url which is basically a locked URL(Mpeg-Dash). I am able to mirror the videos to Apple TV using the Airplay however if the app goes to background, it fails to hold the streaming and it stops.

So, I got to know about the streaming process in Airplay, I am able to create an app and able to stream using Airplay but the format supported are mp4/m3u8. However if I am trying to use the Mpeg-Dash, then its not playing, its stoping the stream when I am trying to start.

Comment: Ok, I assume you mean you're using MPEG-DASH + **CENC** and using Marlin MS3 for your DRM. AFAIK, you can only use Fairplay with Airplay. In fact, I'm not sure how you're doing Airplay with DASH unless you're simply screen mirroring - Big difference!

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack.. You are absolutely correct. If I am doing mirroring.. Its working.. Can't we use casting the Mpeg-dash content?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only do true video handoff Airplay using HLS and optionally with Fairplay.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack as I am using this DRM, I believe I need to use this FairPlay. Could you please help me in resolving this? How to start casting from iOS to Apple Tv using Airplay?

Comment: I think you're best to ask a new question with the specifics you need regarding Fairplay and Airplay.

Comment: @alastair-mccormack
Could you please answer my simple question.. we are depending on Expressplay for the token creation(DRM). Can we use the same HLS url which has been packaged in Expressplay to play in iOS environment using the same HLSCatalog sample app?

Comment: I kindly remind you that I'm under no obligation to answer your question. I do not work for Expressplay, Stackoverflow or Apple. Like others, I answer questions on goodwill. I advise you to raise a new question, which the community will endeavour to answer.